# Can I use Xamarin to write applications for Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, cross-platform

I know Xamarin applications can run on iOS, Android, Windows Phone and Mac OS, but is Windows 7 also a supported platform? My goal is to write a cross-plaftorm application that runs on Windows 7 as well as Android, iOS and Mac OS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean just building a mono application?

Comment: I am not sure what it means because I am new to Xamarin and Mono. Basically, my goal is to write a cross-plaftorm application that runs on Android, iOS, Mac OS and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It will be very difficult write something that is 100% compatible across all devices, but you can write it so that most of it is the same.  Windows, Linux and Mac you can use GTK# for the UI and create common business logic assemblies that are cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

Years later, you could give https://github.com/Atreides07/Xamarin.Forms/tree/wpf a try for a an ongoing implementation for WPF. The author stated somewhere(can´t remember which forum/blog) that he is currently using in production apps.

Comment: Dead link, here is a link to the github page: https://github.com/Atreides07/Xamarin.Forms/ I had to switch to the WPF branch, which looks like it is still active AFAICT